# can't use the same function twice

Tags: python, function, tkinter, time

I'm trying to run a code that use the same function that triggered based on time to show a photo instead of the main photo.
its working fine for the first time calling the function and return back to main photo.but when it call the function for the second time the photo changed I can't see the countdown and the program froze and show error in the terminal field.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root=Tk()
################uper frame for Day---Date----Time#####
frameup=Frame(root,highlightthickness=4,relief='solid',width=1000, height=60)
frameup.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky='nsew',padx=250,pady=5)
frameup.config(highlightbackground='red3')

################lower frame############
framelow=Frame(root,highlightthickness=4,relief='solid',width=800, height=240)
framelow.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=210)
framelow.config(highlightbackground='red3')

################frame Left for the photo#############
frameL=Frame(framelow,width=380,height=20,relief='ridge',highlightthickness=1)
frameL.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5)
frameL.config()

###############frame Right for Time Duration Countdown########
frameR=Frame(framelow)
frameR.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5)
frameR.config(highlightbackground='green')
durationtext=Label(frameR,text='Time Remaining:',font='infra 40 bold')
durationtext.grid(row=0,column=0)

labelTD=Label(frameup)
labelTD.grid(row=0,column=0)

def countdown(n):
    mn, secs =divmod(n, 60)
    hr, mn =divmod(mn, 60)

    labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}")
    labelCD.config(font='infra 50 bold',foreground='black',background='white')

    if n >= 0:
        labelCD.after(1000, countdown, n-1)

    else:
        EYE1.forget()
        labelCD.forget()
        labelCD.destroy()
        StudioC = Label(frameL, image=photoGenral)
        StudioC.grid(row=0, column=0)


def clock():

    t=time.strftime('%A''\t''%D''\t''%H:%M:%S',time.localtime()).upper()

    if t!='':
        labelTD.config(text=t,font='infra 50 bold',foreground='red3',background='white')
        Hr = time.strftime('%H')
        Mn = time.strftime('%M')
        Sc = time.strftime('%S')

        if int(Hr)==7 and int(Mn)==54 and int(Sc)==0: ####just to trigger the timer###
            StudioC.forget()
            EYE1 = Label(frameL, image=photo1)
            EYE1.grid(row=0, column=0)
#######this condition works fine
            countdown(100)

        if int(Hr)==7 and int(Mn)==57 and int(Sc)==0:
            EYE1 = Label(frameL, image=photo1)
            EYE1.grid(row=0, column=0)
###this condition i can see the photo but I can't see countdown function and window froze
            countdown(100)

        if int(Hr)==7 and int(Mn)==59 and int(Sc)==0:
            StudioC.destroy()
            EYE1 = Label(frameL, image=photo1)
            EYE1.grid(row=0, column=0)

            countdown(100)

        labelTD.after(1000,clock)

labelCD = Label(frameR)
labelCD.grid(row=1,column=0)

photo1 = PhotoImage(file="file path.png")
EYE1 = Label(frameL, image=photo1)

#
photoGenral = PhotoImage(file="file path.png")
StudioC = Label(frameL, image=photoGenral)
StudioC.grid(row=0,column=0)


clock()
root.geometry('1775x395')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What error is shown in the terminal window?

Comment: @ scotty3785 its more than one line of error but the two lines specific were 3rd line in countdown function and the second If condition when the window froze.
Please copy past and add two photos to know exactly what i'm talking about.

Comment: Update the question with the full error code please.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__return self.func(*args)
  File "//__init__.py", line 806, in callit func(*args)
  File "/", line 78, in clock countdown(100)
  File "/", line 38, in countdown labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}")
  File "//__init__.py", line 1639, in configure return self._configure('configure',cnf, kw)
  File "//__init__.py", line 1629, in _configure self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame2.!frame2.!label2"

Comment: I had to delete some of the text that showing path to be in the proper count of letters. thanks!

Comment: The error shows that you are calling something you destroyed. You destroyed `labelCD.destroy()` hence it cannot be called with `labelCD.config(....)`, just use `grid_forget()`

Comment: @ Cool Cloud YOU ARE ROCK, thank you!
I added (labelCD.grid(row=1, column=0)) after labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}") to show the counter when it call it again.
why that doesn't happen with the photo? i destroyed it too but it show again and again

Comment: I guess i found the answer for my last question

Comment: @RM2020 Then, check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see how to mark as the answer xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, your are destroying a widget and later using `config()` on a destroyed widget, hence the error. What you could do is instead use `grid_forget()` and then `grid()` it back over each iteration, like:

```
def countdown(n):
    mn,secs = divmod(n, 60)
    hr,mn = divmod(mn, 60)

    labelCD.grid(row=1,column=0) 
    labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}",font='infra 50 bold',
                    foreground='black',background='white')

    if n >= 0:
        labelCD.after(1000, countdown, n-1)

    else:
        EYE1.grid_forget() #hide the widget
        
        if labelCD.winfo_exists(): #if this widget is exists
            labelCD.grid_forget() #then hide
        
        StudioC = Label(frameL, image=photoGenral) #this overlaps the current image
        StudioC.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

If you were to show alternate image over each `if` statement, you could use something like a counter that increases over each iteration and then if it is even then `configure` the label to have one image, if not, then `configure` it to have the other image.

Also instead of using `divmod()`, I would use `timedelta` from `datetime`, like:

```
from datetime import timedelta
....
def countdown(n):
    count = timedelta(seconds=n)

    labelCD.grid(row=1,column=0)
    labelCD.config(text=count,font=.....)
#same code
```

This way, you can save yourself from some of the calculations and formats too.

Comment: I didn't think that `timedelta` gave hours/minutes/seconds just days/minutes/seconds

Comment: My mistake, it does if you get the string. Just not available as a property like `count.hours`

Comment: @scotty3785 Kind of helpful right? That might be because `timedelta` gives a `datetime.timedelta` object which does not have `hours` attribute, unlike `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: @ scotty3785 I guess Cool Cloud has the right answer. I did what he said and its working